# Execute a callback after child component changes its state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class component which renders a child component which cannot be modified (comes from a library).

This component has an internal state in which there is a data I want to retrieve and do something with it as soon at it is changed.

I tried using a callback on ref like this:

```js
onRefChange = el => {
  console.log('el state', el.state);
  // prints the initial state of the child component, with the value still to be changed (it changes a little after initialization)
}

<Carousel
  ref={(el) => {
    this.onRefChange(el);
    return this.Carousel = el;
  }}
  //other stuff
/>
```

Of course I can access the state by reading this.Carousel.state later but I'm trying to do an operation immediately after this data changes, with a callback.

Also apart from changing the behaviour of the child component, the parent component should remain a class componente, so no hooks like useEffect() can be used.

Is it a dead-end or is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Those are really strange constraints. What is it that you originally what to achieve by doing that and what is the name of the library?

Comment: Hi @trixn the name of the library is react-multi-carousel, it has in its state the number of items currently shown (slidesToShow). In this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/SOxWVmd.png the first time is on initialization (0), but soon after it's changed to 7 (not always that so that's why I'm trying to read dinamically), the second console.log is when I slide the carousel, I have a callback there and can read the data there, but I'm trying to execute code as soon as it is set to a value !== 0